# How to set axis date ticks given a starting date in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

While making make a plot with two vectors, for example:

```
plt.plot([1,2,3],[2,4,6])
```

I would like to change my xaxis to date ticks with a given starting, for ex, `"2019-2-28"` then I want my xaxis ticks to be

`["2019-2-28","2019-3-1","2019-3-2"]`

Comment: of course, i want to do it automatically, with a large vector size

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

x= [1,2,3]
y=[2,4,6]
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-2-20')
labels=pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=len(x)),)


plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x,[i.date() for i in labels])
plt.show()
```